# Visual Studio not finding my Specflow tests - possible reasons?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, automated-tests, specflow

I have a .NET 4.8 project with Specflow tests. These are not found and displayed by VS 2019, so I can't execute them. I looked into the log files and found out that VS is trying to execute the tests with testhost.x86.exe although I have set everywhere AnyCPU and Auto as processor architecture (which is enough for other projects). I then set the processor architecture to x64 and now VS is using testhost.exe but still not finding anything. There are no errors in the logs except failing to load Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop extension. What could be the reason for not seeing anything in the test explorer? Or where could I eventually find some more information?

I use the same Specflow (3.1) and Specflow Runner (3.2) versions in other projects and there it works, so it shouldn't be the source of the problem. Also in the project file and elsewhere in the project I couldn't find anything special. All feature files have been generated without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to an older Specflow version (3.0) and it worked. No idea what the problem was but I had it with multiple old projects migrated from Specflow 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fix your issue, but check if you have your Test Explorer set to the same processor architecture as your project.

[image: Visual Studio Test Explorer Processor Architecture selector]

I had some issues with this in the past.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+